# Is using "someone" in a question correct?

Tags: questions, pronouns

When reading about [someone](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/someone) on the OALD, I saw the following note:

> The difference between someone and anyone is the same as the difference between [some](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/some) and [any](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/any). Look at the notes there.

The note that I read for *some* is the following:

> In negative sentences and questions *any* is usually used instead of *some*:
>
> > I don't want any more vegetables.
> >     Is there any wine left?
>
> However, *some* is used in questions that expect a positive reply:
>
> > Would you like some milk in your coffee?
> >     Didn't you borrow some books of mine?

Does that apply to *someone* too? Should I use *someone* in a question when I am expecting a positive answer?

> Does someone know the answer?

Comment: [How to know when to use “someone” or “anyone”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/88225/301031)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your distinctions between *some* and *any* sound correct, though I can't guarantee for certain that there are no exceptions.

*Someone* and *anyone* do not have a set rule, however. There isn't a hard-and-fast rule; they're used differently in different situations.  In some situations there is a slight difference between them, in others I would consider them nearly interchangeable, and in others you must choose one or the other to be properly understood as they can have entirely disparate meanings.

John Lawler's answer [here on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/88230/22119) attempts to explain why there is no set rule for when to use *someone* and *anyone*:

> You are correct. There ***is*** no clear way to do this. Robin Lakoff's paper entitled ["Some Reasons Why There Can't Be *some ~ any* Rule"](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/411442?uid=3739960&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21101202045593) is precisely about this situation.
>
> Short summary of a few of the reasons:
>
> 1. *Any* is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), but *some* isn't.
> 2. Many environments (like questions) allow NPIs like *any*, but don't disallow *some*.
> 3. There are several kinds of *any*, including NPI *any*, and "Free Choice" *any*, as in
>
>    - *Any idiot can solve this problem.*

And to answer the question in your title, it's idiomatic to use *anyone* there; "Is there anyone among you who knows the answer?" (that is, more than one of them could know it). So it should read:

> Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: This seems about right to me. There's no absolute answer, but idiomatically I'd also go for *anyone* rather than *someone* in your final example. Mind you, there's a similar "it all depends, but exactly *what* it depends on is nothing clearly defineable" aspect to the other two possible choices - **anybody** and **somebody**.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of "some milk" or "some books", "some" refers to a known or suspected quantity. "Somebody", like "some", refers to a specific though unnamed person: if it is likely that the answer is known, the "Somebody" in "Does somebody know the answer?" invites a single person to answer (thus avoiding a cacophony of simultaneous related answers).

The "anybody" in "Does anybody know the answer?" presupposes a difficulty or unlikelihood of finding the answer and invites all contributions; similarly "any milk" in the question "Do you want any milk?" refers to a range of possible types and amounts of milk, which may or may not be at hand. In contrast, replacing "any milk" with "some milk" would mean, in effect, "do you want a (limited) portion of the milk I have or could get?"

Answer (score 2):

The examples given are definitely ones in which **some** is a better choice than **any**, but I'm not positive the rule they've given you is the most helpful one to go by. For example, I would ask, "*Would you like **some** milk in your coffee?*" even if I was almost positive the person I was talking to takes their coffee black.

I think the more consistent way of looking at it would be that with **some** there's a specific subset you're referring to, while with **any** there isn't.

> Would you like **some** milk in your coffee?

I probably have a container of milk that I'm offering them, or am prepared to pour some. I'm specifically offering *that milk*. Alternatively, if I was getting up to go fetch some coffee, and before I leave am trying to determine how "you" would like it, I'd be more likely to word it like this:

> Do you want **any** milk in your coffee?

I don't have any milk. I'm asking if you would like the presence of milk -- any milk -- in your coffee.

[It's only fair to note that I may also use this phrasing in the same situation as the example above, and would be more likely to do so if I'm expecting a negative answer. The rule you found about positive and negative expectations was not wrong, I just don't think it's the most helpful way to think about it.]

This is perhaps a little clearer with your other example sentence...

> Didn't you borrow **some** books of mine?
>   Did you borrow **some** books of mine?

There are specific books I have in mind. Perhaps I vaguely remember you asking to borrow some specific titles. Perhaps I'm missing certain volumes from my collection and am wondering if you have them. Compare this to...

> Didn't you borrow **any** books of mine?
>   Did you borrow **any** books of mine?

The implication of each question here is slightly different, but in both I'm referring to the entire set of *my books*. In the first, perhaps I thought you borrowed some books but have realized none of them are missing. Or perhaps you're complaining that you have no books to read and I'm surprised because I thought you took any of mine. In the second, it sounds like I've given you permission to borrow anything from my collection and am just wondering whether or not you've done so.

---

Alright, so now to get to your actual question:
**Yes**, you can use the same rules for *someone* and *anyone*.

> Does **someone** know the answer?
>   Does **anyone** know the answer?

What's the difference here? Honestly, not a lot in this context. I would, however, be more likely to use **anyone** when posting a question on a public forum such as this one, and asking if there was *anyone* out there who may be able to help.

> Is **somebody** in there?
>   Is **anybody** in there?

There's a clearer difference for this question. When I'm asking if **someone** is out there, it does sound like I believe there is. Perhaps I heard a noise. Perhaps the door is locked from the inside. Conversely, when I ask if **anybody** is in there, I don't have an implied expectation. So, your *positive expectation* rule works here. However, so does my *specific subset* rule. If I ask for **somebody** then I'm referring to the person who made that noise I heard, or the person who locked that door from the inside. When I ask for **anybody** I mean just that -- anybody.

And, finally, I'm far more likely to use **anybody** if I think the question may apply to multiple people, while I'll use **somebody** if I only need one person.

> Can **somebody** pass me the rice?

It doesn't matter who passes it, but I only need one person to.

> Has **anybody** seen my keys?

Just because my mom saw them, doesn't mean my dad didn't. Either one, or both, would be able to tell me where to look for my keys.

So, while I said I'd use **anyone** while posting a question here on ELL, I might use **someone** if I worded it differently:

> Does **anyone** know the answer?
>   Can **someone** show me how to do this?

---

There *are* cases where you can jump back and forth or use whichever one appeals to you. However, I think this guideline is a good one to go by. And if you encounter a case where you use it and still aren't sure which word's best then it will usually mean they're both equally acceptable.

Comment: I think that rationale for *"Is somebody/anybody in there?"* is a bit strained, given that the question is addressed to a *possibly non-existent* person (from whom you're expecting an answer if he *does* exist). Would anyone really choose between *somebody/anybody* based on how likely they thought it was that they might get an answer? In fact, my logic tells me that probably you *do* think someone's there, if you're asking the question at all. Google Books confirms *"Hello? Is **anybody** there?"* is far more common than the ***somebody*** version (where "Hello?" implies you think they exist).

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers, and I also find your milk example odd; I can't imagine why I would ask *Do you want any milk in your coffee?* if I didn't *have* any milk. That seems a pointless question, and therefore a pointless distinction. I think this is probably not as complicated as it seems; I have a feeling this is one of those things where there isn't so much a *rule* as an idiomatic set of *what sounds right and when* (and some cases where you *must* use one). [John Lawler's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/88230/22119) to a similar question on ELU seems to support this.

Comment: I'm trying to pin down a guideline that helps a non-native speaker pick the most appropriate word when they don't yet have the familiarity to know which "feels right." Despite the above comments about my rationale, I maintain I will be more likely to offer "any milk" before I run to the coffee shop, "some milk" if I'm about to pour what I have, for "someone" if I heard something, and "anyone" if I didn't. I agree there isn't a hard rule (as I said flip-flopping is often acceptable). But rather, I do think this thought process will generally get you to the word with the correct implication.

Comment: I certainly think there's *something* in what you say, but I can't help feeling the net effect is to make it all seem far more complicated than it really is. If I'd answered, I think the first point I'd have made is that almost certainly the vast majority of native speakers wouldn't use *either* determiner when simply asking "**Would you like milk in your coffee?**"

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that 'any' has  a separate use where it applies the meaning 'it does not matter which/where/what', it can be any of it/anywhere/anything/anyone.
For instance:

> With this season ticket you can take any buses.

Therefore I have the feeling that the question may try to point out that within a specific group any individual is allowed to speak up and try to answer, when we say

> Does anybody/anyone know the answer?