# The difference between "somebody" & "anybody" & someone" ,specifically in this context

Tags: word-usage

> Do you know somebody here?
>
> Do you know anybody here?
>
> Do you know someone here?

If there is any difference in meaning, could you please paraphrase each question, so that I could understand what the differences are.

Comment: The most common usage is *Do you know **anybody** here?* The other two are equivalent to each other, and would normally only be used in contexts where the expected answer is *Yes* (often because that's the reason you're there in the first place). Compare the negated form ***Don't** you know anybody here?*, which would only rarely occur with ***someone, somebody*** (again, probably in expectation of an affirmative response).

Comment: See also [anyone vs someone? Which one](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16132/anyone-vs-someone-which-one).

Answer (score -1):

My opinion:

> - Do you know someone here? -- Do you know some person here well?
> - Do you know somebody here? -- Do you know some person here, at least who can recognize you?
> - Do you know anybody here? -- Do you know some person here, at least by name?

My answer is coming from a simple resolution. "Some" - is a choice from specific options. "Any" - from all options available. "One" - is often meaning for a person, while "body" - is just a human (or any) object.