# Which is the correct choice in this sentence, "anyone", "anybody", or "someone"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I think you can say **anyone**, my teacher says no and insists on **anybody** and my sister, an almost English major says it's **someone**. This was an exercise that you had to complete a sentence with an indefinite pronoun or an adverb.

> Can ______ help me prepare lunch?

Comment: Your teacher is mistaken. [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/anyone-anybody-or-anything) - ***Anyone** and **anybody** have no difference in meaning.* But they're *not* the same as ***someone, somebody***. Offhand I can't think of any context where those last two aren't 100% equivalent, but I stand to be corrected on that point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [anyone vs someone. Which one?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16132/anyone-vs-someone-which-one) See also [Anyone/anybody- someone/somebody](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/221355/anyone-anybody-someone-somebody) and [The difference between “somebody” & “anybody” & someone" ,specifically in this context,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58156/) among others.

Comment: Probable duplicate of [Anyone/anybody- someone/somebody](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/221355). I have moved my response, and would suggest closing this question.

Answer (score -1):

[Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/anyone-anybody-or-anything) say:

*Anyone and anybody have no difference in meaning. Anybody is a little less formal than anyone. Anyone is used more in writing than anybody.*

To me, *anyone* seems natural in the context of your request for help because it suggests 'any one of you'.