# Difference between 'anybody', 'somebody', 'someone', 'nobody'

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What is the difference between *anybody,somebody,someone,nobody*? And when should we use one or another of them?

It's a bit confusing to me.

Example:

> Does (anybody/somebody/someone/nobody) want a game of tennis ?

Comment: I put it on hold because it is not clear why a dictionary isn't able to answer your question. If you add more explanation, we may be able to reopen this.

Comment: i've provided an example

Comment: @ColleenV Dictionaries can't deal with function words - which is why they are studied in grammar lessons and not vocabulary lessons! :-) This is a common source of confusion for learners, is not easy and cannot be cleared up by a dictionary. But worse than that it is not easy to explain *why* they are confusing. (If you want to see that more clearly, see if you think you could explain the difference to a friend!)

Comment: @ColleenV For example, a dictionary won't tell you that *anybody* is a negative polarity item and that it's use is restricted in positive sentences. Consider "I saw anybody in town yesterday". Or "Did you find anything?" "Yes, I did find anything". That cannot be cleared up by a dictionary! :-)

Comment: @Araucaria I do know all of this, which is why I closed it as needing more detail and not "answerable by a dictionary". I just wanted to see a little more effort put into the question. Asking why the dictionary didn't help was intended to be a starting point to think about why it was confusing. The meanings don't help us know when to use them.

Comment: As a non-native I had to read a few spurces myself to find out this difference. Fortunately, there is so much info on the web and so many places to find the answers.

Comment: Why off-topic? It's really a very interesting question for an English learner!

Answer (score 2):

> Does (anybody/somebody/someone) want a game of tennis?

The words "somebody" and "someone" [are essentially identical and can be used interchangeably.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1754/970) This applies to the words "anybody" and "anyone" as well. [This answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/16157/698) explains the differences between "anyone" and "someone".

In this particular case, "Does anyone..." is the more common phrasing.

[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) is a useful tool for determining which word appears more commonly in literature. ["someone" occurred more frequently than "somebody" in each year after 1920](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=someone%2C+somebody&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3):

[image: graph]

> Does nobody want a game of tennis?

This sentence assumes that nobody wants to play tennis and asks if anyone will deny that this is true. It may also imply disbelief that nobody wants a game of tennis. Although correct, the more common phrasing of this question would be:

> Doesn't anybody want a game of tennis?