# Determiners: anyone versus someone

Tags: determiners, indefinite-pronouns

Can anyone explain the difference between:
"Can anyone answer me "  and
"Can someone answer me " ?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [anyone vs someone. Which one?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/16132) [Difference between 'anybody', 'somebody', 'someone', 'nobody'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/123491)

Answer (score 4):

"Any" and "Some" can be called as "prefixes and determiners of quantity", by that I mean they can be used in expressions such as - *anyone, anybody, somebody, something,  anything, anywhere, somewhere, etc.*

With that being said, "any" is mainly used in interrogative and negative *[that is lacking affirmative meaning]* sentences "where you do not expect any quantity".
for instance:

***Can anyone tell me what is going on here? (= If there is only one, tell me - referring to an unspecified amount)***

***Can somebody tell me what is going on here? (= I expect to be told what is going on here, or there is probably some person who can tell me that )***

Non-affirmative sentence example:

**Nobody was in the room. ( the room was empty. )**
*whereas*

**Somebody was not in the room. ( there was some [unspecified] person who was not in the room )**

Moreover, "any" is mostly used along with adverbs which emphasize quantity such as - hardly, barely, scarcely, never, seldom, rarely - and, also, some negative verbs (fail, forbid, prohibit, prevent) and adjectives (unlikely, unable, impossible, etc.).

*Because of the characteristics mentioned above, words associated with *"any"* take place in inversion as well.
e.g.*

***Hardly* had *anyone* seen her before her leaving.**

*I hope I provided useful information on this particular topic.*

Comment: "hardly had anyone seen her" is awkward. Hardly anyone had seen her before she left.