# But vs Except usage

Tags: adverbs

> 1. She has no one to look after her **except** me.
> 2. She has no one to look after her **but** me.

Which is correct?

My grammar book says sentence2 is correct. What is the difference between BUT and EXCEPT in these kind of sentences? Aren’t they always replacable?

Comment: I'd prefer to use ***"except (for), or apart/aside from me"*** rather than ***"but"***. Both of the sentences are synonymous with one another; *thus, I don't think there is much noticeable differentiation between them except for the latter being more emphatic than the former... Look it up in your favorite dictionary for more information about **both 'but' and 'except' functioning as a preposition in a sentence...***

Comment: @AlexRaw Are but and Except always replaceable in these kind of sentences?

Comment: Yes. They are interchangeable.

Comment: @AlexRaw, I preferred your comment than the available answer. Would you consider register it in an answer? It seems to have helped the asker as helped me

Comment: @AlexRaw.  Is it same when No One Else is used? Like, She has no one else to look after her EXCEPT me = She has no one else to look after her BUT me. Are they same?

Comment: @ramtejaguthikonda You should not look at the sentence in that way, but *"no"*. They are not the same as words if they are synonymous with one other; they are ***syntactically the same***: *both of them are prepositions.* Another possible variant of "no one" is none other than "nobody". e.g. ***She has not anyone/anybody to look after her but me.***  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/244884/determiners-anyone-versus-someone

Answer (score -1):

"But" can be used as a preposition in the sense of "except" :

> "She has no one to look after her **but/except** me."

Therefore, both your examples are okay & interchangeable.

Comment: Yes. I've edited.